# window.beforeunload called before WebViewClient.shouldOverrideUrlLoading

Tags: android, webview, android-webview, android-webview-javascript

In the Android app with the WebView and WebViewClient configured, after the [window.open(url, '_system')](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_open.asp) called from the js, the js event [window.beforeunload](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onbeforeunload.asp) is fired before the Android [WebViewClient.shouldOverrideUrlLoading](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebViewClient#shouldOverrideUrlLoading(android.webkit.WebView,%20android.webkit.WebResourceRequest)) is called. Is this a proper and intended behavior? Is there a way to intercept the url open without the window.beforeunload event fired?

Comment: To stop the `window.beforeunload` from being fired what you have tried??

Comment: @chiragsoni I have presumed that using WebViewClient.shouldOverrideUrlLoading would cancel any further js events related to the window.open, was I wrong?

Comment: I am not sure about this.

Answer (score 1):

see this example code, maybe help you:

```
    final WebView webView = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.webview);

    // Enable javascript
    webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

    webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {

        @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
            final Uri uri = Uri.parse(url);
            return customUriHanlder(uri);
        }

        @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, WebResourceRequest request) {
            final Uri uri = request.getUrl();
            return customUriHanlder(uri);
        }

        private boolean customUriHanlder(final Uri uri) {
            Log.i(TAG, "Uri =" + uri);
            final String host = uri.getHost();
            final String scheme = uri.getScheme();
            // you can set your specific condition
            if (true) {
                // Returning false means that you are going to load this url in the webView itself
                return false;
            } else {
                // Returning true means that you need to handle what to do with the url
                // open web page in a Browser
                final Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri);
                startActivity(intent);
                return true;
            }
        }

    });

    // Load the webpage
    webView.loadUrl("https://google.com/");
```

with `customUriHanlder` function you can load your url in vebview itself or in browser.
on google documentation `shouldOverrideUrlLoading`: If a WebViewClient is provided, returning `true` causes the current WebView to abort loading the URL, while returning `false` causes the WebView to continue loading the URL as usual.